# Two stage amplifier, low gain at high frequencies

Tags: transistors, amplifier, gain, high-frequency

When I simulate one stage amplifier it is capable of amplifying to a much higher frequency than a two stage amplifier.

I added a 100 ohm resistor to reduce the gain of the two stage amplifier so both the gain curves could fit in one graph, but you get my point. The two stage amplifier is dying much earlier than the single stage.

Why is that?

Can I prevent this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you replicate R36 in the right-side schematic?

Comment: It is confusing I know, but I explained it in question: I added 100 ohm to reduce gain of two stage amplifier, so both gain curves could fit in one graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first stage has a comparatively high output impedance (approximately 470 Ohms) relative to your 1V AC source resistance, which is presumably quite small. This resistance is seen as an effective source resistance to your second stage. The 470 Ohm resistance acts together with the capacitance of Q8 between the base and the collector to form a low-pass filter at the input of Q8. Due to the [Miller Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect), this capacitance is effectively amplified by the gain of your second stage....which is around 90 or so. That is, the capacitance looks like a capacitor about 90 times larger than the actual base-collector capacitance, connected between the Q8 base and ground (the Miller Effect).

According to the BC817-40 datasheet, this capacitance is about 10pF. The effective capacitance seen at the input of Q8 is therefore around 900pF, so your 3dB rolloff will occur around \$f_{3dB} =\frac{1}{2\pi RC} = \frac{1}{2\pi\cdot 470 \cdot 900 \cdot 10^{-12}} = 380 \text{kHz}\$. From your graph, this looks about right.

A good solution is to use a [Cascode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode#:%7E:text=The%20cascode%20is%20a%20two,high%20output%20impedance%2C%20higher%20bandwidth.) configuration on your second stage to keep the Q8 collector at a steady voltage, circumventing the Miller Effect.

Comment: You were right, when I added second transistor, pole shifted to higher frequencies. Thank you very much for advice!